# What are the conditions for bread earning the bracha of HaMotzi?

Tags: blessing, mezonot-beracha, hamotzi-beracha

I've seen bread made with juice on airplanes and the insert says these are "mezonos" rolls.  And, as we know, matzah is "HaMotzi."

In the first instance, it looks like bread but we treat it like cake, and in the second instance, it looks like a cracker/cake and we treat it like bread.

I thought the **ingredients** determine the bracha!

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3248/759

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is mazonot?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3682/what-is-mazonot)

Comment: You agree that pasta and bread have the same ingredients...

Comment: @ShmuelBrin: I understand the reasoning of why this would be considered bread, so what is the reasoning why some poskim (London Beis Din) consider it mezonos?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin: Also, there is a custom to give egg matzah or "rich" matzah to children and older people erev pesach, as these do not have the same status as lechem oni.  Are you saying the bracha for those should also be Hamotzi?

Comment: @wizlog "Matza Ashira" is "Pas Habbah Bekisnin" type 1 (it is allowed *only* if there is no water at all in the Matza). Therefore, it is Mezonos.

Comment: @wizlog - Can you pls bring a source that the LBD considers M.A. mezonos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For something baked to be Mezonos it [must fulfill](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25072&st=&pgnum=720) one of the following requirements:

1. The dough is so liquidy one cannot roll it in one's hands and one fries it in a pan.
2. The dough is so liquidy one cannot roll it in one's hands and one fries it in a hole in an oven (so it gathers in one spot and becomes thick there).
3. Pas Habaah Bekisnin - There are three opinions as to what this refers to:

   - Normal bread that was kneaded with a majority of fruit juice.
   - Some say that the above mentioned "PAs Habbah Bekisnin" is normal bread. This opinion says that "Pas Habbah Bekisnin" is bread that we filled with a sweet filling before baking (so the filling is the ikkar and the bread is the tafel).

The Halacha is that one could rely on the first opinion, but a Baal nefesh should be stringent and wash on normal bread before eating.

---

Mezonos bread served on an airplane is "Pas Habbah Bekisnin" of the first variety. It is made from water and apple juice, so technically, it is a mezonos. As "flat bread" isn't on this list, it is Hamotzi.

This list is **for Ashkenazim** only. The Beis Yosef *does* add "flat crackers" to the list of "Pas Habbah Bekisnin" and therefore, SEfardim don't wash on Matzo year round.

Comment: You didn't qualify that pat haba'ah bekisanin only gets mezonot when outside of a meal.

Comment: Also, noodles are mezonot because they aren't baked!

Comment: @DoubleAA: But bagels aren't baked either, I thought!

Comment: @wizlog I'm under the impression that some bagels are baked and some are boiled and some are boiled and then baked. If it is only boiled then it may in fact be only a mezonot.

Comment: I'd like one more response to my question before I designate this answer, as correct.