# Are corn chips mazonot?

Tags: blessing, food, mezonot-beracha

On Chanukah this year we will make a blessing on wine and then having latkas, etc.. I am looking for something mazonot to serve after the wine bracha which is not sweet. We are not making Hamotzi. Are corn chips mazonot? What other non sweet simple food would be mazonot?

Comment: juliet, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! I hope you get a good answer to your question. I also hope you'll look around and find other information here that's to your taste, perhaps including our 412 other [tag:blessing] questions. Also, please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Corn is never mezonot.

Comment: I'd go with pretzels or crackers.

Comment: Also note that the Mezonoth should be recited before the wine Berachah.

Comment: Discussion is ongoing in [chat].

Comment: Hi Juliet and welcome to Mi Yodeya.  There is some discussion about whether your question is more about the br'acha on corn chips or more about recommendations, and if the latter, how best to cast it.  I'm going to put this on hold (to prevent more answers) while that gets sorted out.  [This](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12142692#12142692) is one proposal for an edit.  Could we have your input on all this, in a comment or an [edit]?  Thanks!

Comment: Is this question about what to eat following kiddush on Shabbat (that happens to fall on Chanukah)? That's my impression from your stated desire to serve *m'zonot* after wine. If so, disregard @SethJ 's comment about the order of blessings.

Comment: @yitznewton http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12144740#12144740

Answer (score 2):

[The Berachot Site](http://www.berachot.org/) (whose sources are explained [here](http://www.berachot.org/AboutUs/aboutus.html)), [lists](http://www.berachot.org/foods/letter_c.html) corn chips as requiring a "Shehakol," presumably because they don't [contain](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3683/2) flour made of one of the primary grains.

(However, note that in a case where flour from one of the five m'zonos grains is even a minority ingredient in the chips, the chips would still require a blessing of m'zonos unless the flour is only in the food as a binding agent or for the consistency of the food or some such ([Shulchan Aruch OC 208:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1032)). Thanks to [Fred](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1442/fred) for pointing this out in a comment.)

You can look through the listings at that site for ideas for foods that require a "Mezonot." The first savory snack foods that come to mind are pretzels and crackers.

Answer (score 1):

Try Bissli  from Osem or Super Snacks from Ki Tov. You could also use Chow Mein Noodles or Croutons (soup Mandle).

These are all Mezonos and not sweet.

There are some onion rings that are Mezonos.

Answer (score 0):

[Shibolim crackers](http://shibolim.com/shibolim/product-category/crackers/) are delicious, healthy, not sweet, and Mezonos.

Comment: Probably depends how many you eat.

Comment: @double aa, also depends on whether you like that sort of thing. ("Delicious")

Comment: @SethJ Yes, but my factor affects the Mezonos status, which is the essential one for the answer.