# What to do if you made hamotze on something requiring mezonot?

Tags: blessing, mistakes, bentching, bread

If you accidentally made a hamotze on a food item only requiring mezonot, do you say al hamichya or birkat hamazon for the beracha acharona?

Comment: The bracha achrona is not dependent on the bracha rishona

Comment: Are _m'zonos_ bagels merely an example of something that's _m'zonos_, or is that precisely the food you're asking about? If the former, you've picked [a poor example](/q/3248), and I recommend [edit]ing it out. If otoh the latter, then I recommend editing to clarify that that's the food you're asking about specifically, and why it's worth asking about specifically.

Comment: If you eat a "whole meal" of it, that satiates yourself, it requires Birkat Hamazon according to most authorities. Possibly all of them, just they may differ on the quantity.

Comment: @CashCow That's not true of all mezonos things. Only pas haba b'kisnin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked my rav (who is from Ner Yisrael in Baltimore) and he said that that the bracha on a item is conected to the food that is eaten only. The bracha acharonah is **not** (in that sense) connected to the bracha rishona. Thus if one makes the **wrong** bracha rishona, one should still make the correct bracha acharona.

He said that since the bracha rishona and the bracha acharona are separate bodies of halacha, the poskim do not discuss your case.

He also pointed out that the example given ("mezonos" bagels) is incorrect and you should have used cake. For example see [What is mazonot?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3682/what-is-mazonot?rq=1) That is, your question is about making the wrong bracha rishona and you are giving a case in which the correct bracha rishona is indeed hamotzi, which would require birchas hamazon (according to many poskim). That example makes the premise of your question wrong. It would have been better to have given an example which is definitely (according to all poskim) mezonos.

He also pointed out that you could have used the example of water or fruit to show why the correct brachah acharona must be made even if the wrong bracha rishona was made and why it is not given as an explicit halacha.

There are discussions as to what must be done if the wrong bracha rishona is made (and how to fix it). However, especially with pas haba be'kisnin (mezonos), the matter is too complicated to put into a post like here and I would probably make mistakes in trying to write about it.

Comment: How can an example given be incorrect? Changing his question so you can answer it doesn't mean you answered his question.

Comment: @DoubleAA the point is that the example undercuts his question by giving an example which many poskim state should be hamotzi and birchas hamazon. To give force to the question, the example should be something that everyone agrees should be mezonos.

Comment: The example doesn't undercut anything. If I gave Matza as the example in the question would that undercut it because Ashkenazim say HaMotzi on it? The intent of the question is very clear, so the question is not undercut nor does it not have force. What's the bigger issue is you should not be telling the OP that his psak about mezonot rolls is wrong. You can tell him it's a minority opinion or something like that.

Comment: @DoubleAA OK ignore the example. THe question is if someone makes the wrong bracha rishona, what is done for the bracha acharona and that is what I answered.