# Do I need to wash and bentch on oatmeal?

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing, bentching, mezonot-beracha, hamotzi-beracha

I was reading in Artscroll's *[The Laws of Brachos](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1284490.Laws_of_Brachos_Artscroll)* that if someone eats an amount of mezonos equal to the amount of bread he would have eaten during a meal then he needs to wash and bentch. For some reason it seems to not be the case, but should I be washing/bentching for oatmeal (or even any bowl of morning cereal made from the 5 grains)? If not what's the reason?

Comment: Hmmm ... good question. You're making me wonder. For that matter, perhaps if you plan on eating a whole box of Tam Tams, you may have to wash too.

Comment: Note that oatmeal might not be mezonos

Comment: Boiled mezonos is different from baked mezonos. I suspect you missed something in the book there

Comment: @DoubleAA, Correct, the chapter was referring to Pas haba beKisnin I mistakened it for all mezonos.

Comment: @DoubleAA: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53871/what-exactly-is-shibbolet-shual

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

There are three categories of grain-based products:

- "Bread." Always *hamotzee*.
- "Snacky, quasi-breadlike substances." (*Pas haba beKisnin*.) *Mezonos*, but if you eat them like a meal, then *hamotzee.* This was the category about which you read.
- "Definitely not bread." Always *mezonos*, even if you ate ten pounds of the stuff for dinner. (Though you'd have bigger problems at that point than the laws of brachos.)

Cooked-in-liquid things like noodles and oatmeal are in this last category.

[Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 48:8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41276&pgnum=163) reads:

> Dough -- even a basic, breadlike flour-and-water dough -- if it was cooked, the blessing beforehand is *mezonos* and afterwards *al hamichya*, even if one ate enough to be satiated. **The same goes for mashes made off the five grains [wheat/barley/spelt/oats/rye] and then cooked -- the blessing is *borei minei mezonos* beforehand and *al himchya* afterwards, even if one ate enough to be satieted.** The same goes for noodles eaten with broth or milk in which they were cooked.

Comment: Can you define what is meant by "Definitely not bread"? I would say marble cake is "definitely not bread" but it's under the category of Pas haba beKisnin.

Comment: @AniYodea that's a different question! Noodles and oatmeal -- definitely not bread. Cheerios -- most poskim hold definitely not bread, but Dayan Feurst holds they're in the middle category. Marble cake is a thin batter baked in an oven, which is one of the categories classically described as the second category.

Comment: More here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3683/21